diff in odeint requires input that is one dimensional
I have a solver that is using odeint and I have a 2nd order differential equation. When I am substituting the z-values in the solver I am encountering the error:
ValueError: diff requires input that is at least one dimensional
But I am unsure whether the issue is with the input or another step.
def H_value(derivs, zPnt, H0, OmegaM0, lambd0):
    # reduced Hubble constant
    h0 = H0 / 100

    Omega_rad_0 = 4.183699 * (10 ** (-5)) / h0 ** 2
    Omegar0 = 0.000084
    OmegaL0 = (1 - 0.3 - Omegar0)

    Vphi_0 = 3*H0**2*(1 - OmegaM0 - Omegar0) #insert potential here

    #1st and 2nd derivatives of phi
    dphidz, dpsidz = derivs

    #derivs[0] = 1
    #derivs[1] = 0
    lambd = lambd0

    #1st Friedmann
    H_sol = 1/12 * (derivs[1] ** 2 + (2 * derivs[1] ** 2 * zPnt) + derivs[1] ** 2 * zPnt ** 2 + np.sqrt(((derivs[1] ** 2 + (2 * derivs[1] ** 2 * zPnt) + derivs[1] ** 2 * zPnt ** 2) ** 2 + 24 * (6* H0**2*OmegaM0 + 6*H0**2*Omegar0+2*V_pot(derivs[0], Vphi_0, lambd) + 18*H0**2*OmegaM0*zPnt+24*H0**2*Omegar0*zPnt+18*H0**2*OmegaM0*zPnt**2+36*H0**2*Omegar0*zPnt**2+6*H0**2*OmegaM0*zPnt**3+24*H0**2*Omegar0*zPnt**3+6*H0**2*Omegar0*zPnt**4))))

    #2nd Friedmann
    H_prime = (1/(2*(1 + zPnt) * H_sol) * (H_sol**2 * (3 + (Omegar0*(1 + zPnt)**4) + (((1 + zPnt)**2)/2)*derivs[1]**2) - V_pot(derivs[0], Vphi_0, lambd) - (6*H0**2*OmegaL0)))

    #Klein-Gordon
    dpsidz = - (1/((1 + zPnt)**2 *H_sol**2))*((1 + zPnt)**2*H_sol*H_prime -
    2*(1 + zPnt)*(H_prime**2)) * derivs[1] - (dVdphi(derivs[0], Vphi_0, lambd)/((1 + zPnt)**2*H_sol**2))
    return [dphidz, dpsidz]

def H_solversols(zPoints, H0, OmegaM0, phi0, dphidz0, lambd0):
    #y00 = [phi0, dphidz0]
    Omegar0 = 0.000084
    V_phi0 = 3*H0**2*(1 - OmegaM0 - Omegar0) * np.exp(lambd0)
    odesolver = odeint(H_value, [phi0, dphidz0], zPoints, args=(H0, OmegaM0,lambd0))
    phi00 = odesolver[:, 0]
    dphi00 = odesolver[:, 1]
    H_finalvals = 1/12 * (dphi00 ** 2 + (2 * dphi00 ** 2 * zPoints) + dphi00 ** 2 * zPoints ** 2 + np.sqrt(((dphi00 ** 2 + (2 * dphi00 ** 2 * zPoints) + dphi00 ** 2 * zPoints ** 2) ** 2 + 24 * (6* H0**2*OmegaM0 + 6*H0**2*Omegar0+2*V_pot(phi00, V_phi0, lambd0) + 18*H0**2*OmegaM0*zPoints+24*H0**2*Omegar0*zPoints+18*H0**2*OmegaM0*zPoints**2+36*H0**2*Omegar0*zPoints**2+6*H0**2*OmegaM0*zPoints**3+24*H0**2*Omegar0*zPoints**3+6*H0**2*Omegar0*zPoints**4))))

    if any(h_val<0 or np.isnan(h_val) for h_val in H_finalvals):
        return [np.inf]
    return H_finalvals

I have tried to amend other parts of the solver but I am unsure of what type of input is required.

Please add the error message to the question text (in code-fences, with lang-none). Try to reduce the complexity of the equation while preserving the same structure, so that you still get the same error for a smaller (and complete, runnable) example.
